# determine highest double value of 5 double values

Tags: android

I develop a gesture App. For this I need to have the highest score value of the drawn gesture.

So I actually have got 5 different double score values, like this:

```
06-04 00:38:34.605  21423-21423/de.gestureanywhere D/score﹕ score 3.6936744465393905|GOF2
06-04 00:38:34.605  21423-21423/de.gestureanywhere D/score﹕ score 2.021340609760623|Uhr
06-04 00:38:34.610  21423-21423/de.gestureanywhere D/score﹕ score 1.942381354120031|Spare Parts
06-04 00:38:34.610  21423-21423/de.gestureanywhere D/score﹕ score 1.1174127455877019|Screenshot Leicht
06-04 00:38:34.610  21423-21423/de.gestureanywhere D/score﹕ score 1.025620059028788|Shell
```

How to programmatically get the highest double value of `prediction.score` of These values (so in this example 3.69)?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Double.MAX_VALUE
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE

> A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double,
>   (2-2-52)·21023. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal
>   0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023 and also equal to
>   Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7fefffffffffffffL).

#### update:

```
      List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
      values.add(new double[] {3.6936744465393905});
      values.add(new double[] {2.021340609760623});
      values.add(new double[] {1.942381354120031});
      values.add(new double[] {1.1174127455877019});
      values.add(new double[] {1.025620059028788});               

      double min=Double.MAX_VALUE, max=Double.MIN_VALUE;
      for (double[] ds : values) {
          for (double d : ds) {
              if (d > max) max=d;
              if (d < min ) min=d;
          }
      }       
      Log.i(TAG," Max value is: " + max);
```

Comment: sorry. I need the highest double value of those 5 values (so in this example 3.69)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the values in a list...

```
public double getMaxValue(List<Double> values){
   double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   for(Double d : values){
      maxValue = d > maxValue ? d : maxValue;
   }
}
```

or if concerned about performance...

```
public double getMaxValue(List<Double> values){
   double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   for(Double d : values){
      if(d > maxValue){
         d = maxValue
      }
   }
}
```

The first one makes always an assignation, meanwhile the second one only if the new value is greater than the old value.